# What property of prime numbers have I ran into?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Preface: I don't have *any* background in number theory, but I tried researching this first.

The other day I noticed that if I start with the number $11$ and add $18$ to it repeatedly, most of the subsequent numbers (at least at the start) *also* have a digit sum of 2 if I repeatedly reduce the digit sum until I have a single number.

i.e.
\begin{align*}
11 &\rightarrow 1 + 1 = 2 \\
11+18 = 29 &\rightarrow 2 + 9 = 11 \rightarrow 1 + 1 = 2 \\
29 + 18 = 47 &\rightarrow 4 + 7 = 11 \rightarrow 1 + 1 = 2
\end{align*}

Also, most of the numbers in this period of 18 are prime!

Then I realized that I could do the same digit sum classification with the numbers $[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]$ respectively, and it looks like I am accounting for *all* primes (and some non primes) by adding $18$ to some starting value. (*sum below means **digit sum***)

```
    1 start , sum 1  11 start, sum 2  13 start, sum 4  17 start, sum 8  \
0                 1               11               13               17   
1                19               29               31               35   
2                37               47               49               53   
3                55               65               67               71   
4                73               83               85               89   
5                91              101              103              107   
6               109              119              121              125   
7               127              137              139              143   
8               145              155              157              161   
9               163              173              175              179   
10              181              191              193              197   

    5 start, sum 5  7 start, sum 7  
0               23               7  
1               41              25  
2               59              43  
3               77              61  
4               95              79  
5              113              97  
6              131             115  
7              149             133  
8              167             151  
9              185             169  
10             203             187
```

If I make a mask where $\text{True}$ indicates the number is prime

```
    1 start , sum 1  11 start, sum 2  13 start, sum 4  17 start, sum 8  \
0              True             True             True             True   
1              True             True             True            False   
2              True             True            False             True   
3             False            False             True             True   
4              True             True            False             True   
5             False             True             True             True   
6              True            False            False            False   
7              True             True             True            False   
8             False            False             True            False   
9              True             True            False             True   
10             True             True             True             True   

    5 start, sum 5  7 start, sum 7  
0             True            True  
1             True           False  
2             True            True  
3            False            True  
4            False            True  
5             True            True  
6             True           False  
7             True           False  
8             True            True  
9            False           False  
10           False           False
```

So then I pushed a Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm past $10 ^ 8$ and witnessed that the membership frequency of the next $1000$ primes were near-equal across the 6 different classes below, and all looked to be accounted for. I would also be curious to see how the frequency of composites in the series increase (as I'm sure they do) as the series gets longer.

**Question**

This seems like it would be a technique to reduce the number of values one would have to check to generate prime numbers. Is there a name for a technique like this (assuming my maths aren't entirely wrong here), and is ther some special quality about the number $18$ that allows me to add it like this to get digit sums like below?

Comment: You've run into the property that a number $x$ and the sum of its digits have the same remainder modulo $9$. Of course, since the procedure terminates, you'll always end up with a number in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. Prime numbers $\ge5$ cannot have remainders $0$, $3$ or $6$, otherwise they'd be in the form $p=9h+3$ (or $6$ or $0$) and thus multiples of three. A special instance of this fact is taught in primary school as "divisibility criteria by $3$ or $9$".

Comment: @G.Sassatelli That pretty much clears up my moment of wonder. if you wanted to put that comment in an answer I would be happy to accept it, but in any case thank you!